# Setting 2D array as hash value in map C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, hash, hashmap

My definition for the map is the following:

```
map<vector<int>, double[][2] > my_dicts;
```

I have a 2D array name dictpreComputation and vector of int called homo which is declared as follows:

```
double dictpreComputation[newtable.size()][2] = {0.0};
vector<int> homo;
```

When i am trying to initialize my_dicts as:

```
my_dicts[homo] = dictpreComputation;
```

It is giving the error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds. Can anybody tell what is wrong and what is the correct way of performing this action?

Comment: This `double dictpreComputation[newtable.size()][2] = {0.0};` only compiles due to a GCC extension. This is not standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy an array. Maybe assign each cell separately.

For example if the value was a 1D array:

```
 my_dicts[homo][0] = 0;
```